# How to filter messages in Thunderbird to forward all messages with attachments?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter, attachments

How to create a filter to process (eg. forward) all messages having attachments in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Comment: are you trying to process more than one message simultaneously, or are you trying to simply include the attachment with forwarded messages when you forward one message?

Comment: @User91232 I want to forward all messages having attachments to another email, once they are fetched by Thunderbird.

Comment: It is very odd that you can search for attachments, but you cannot filter on them. I have looked for an add-on to do it, and not found one. I hoped it would be possible to search the body for the heading "Content-Disposition: attachment;", but alas headers are excluded from body searches. I came up with two partial solutions: (1) create a search folder containing the attachments and process the messages in that; (2) filter on e-mail size (excludes small attachments) or body containing "attach" (not always reliable). I'll keep looking, but I'm not very hopeful at present.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I came to a solution was to create a filter using the message header `Content-Type`:

> Content-Type | contains | multipart/mixed

Plowing through my mails sources, I noticed that `Content-Type:` in most cases is set to `multipart/mixed` in mails with attachments and `multipart/alternative` in mails without attachments.

But this would've been to easy, right? There is an exception (... possibly more):

> Some **Apple Mail** clients seem to not set `multipart/mixed`

It's the only one I found in my mails, so at least I can filter my invoices ... nobody in finance uses Apple Mail :)

Hope it helps. Cheers.

---

**Update**

I just tested this with an Apple Mail client and it works, too. Updated the answer above.